# MacBook connected to the iMac keep on disconnecting

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac, zoom.app, universal-control

**Setup**

I've got an iMac on Ventura 13.5 with a connected Magic Mouse and a Magic Keyboard. I am sharing the Magic Mouse and the keyboard with another Mac (Ventura 13.5). The two devices are a foot apart, they both are connected to the same Wi-Fi, and both are signed in with the same Apple ID. The *Mac* has a second monitor connected to it via HDMI.

[image: Screenshot of the Display settings arranged in the following order: iMac MacBook, and Dell monitor]

**Problem**

With increasing frequency, the iMac has started to randomly disconnects from the MacBook. Then, one will only see the image on the Display settings.  This is rather annoying as I use the mouse and the keyboard to work on the MacBook.

Edit : To add more clarity, the issue as far as I understand is that the Mac display gets disconnected. That is, I can only see the iMac under the displays in the attached image. As a consequence of this disconnection, the universal control fails too.

**Attempted troubleshooting**

1. Updated both the iMac and the MacBook to Ventura 13.5
2. Switched off and switched on both the keyboard and the mouse.
3. I noted previously when I am in a Zoom meeting on the iMac, the MacBook gets disconnected from it. But I do not have Zoom open anymore.

Comment: When you say “the iMac randomly disconnects” are you referring to [Universal Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212757)?  Your question refers to a mouse/keyboard but then goes to “Display settings”. It’s tough to follow. Can you [edit] with some clarification?

Comment: Thanks @Allan, I might be getting confused with the terminology as I'm fairly new to the Mac setup. I've edited the question now.